# Ionic 2 - Disable side menu in log in page

Tags: angular, ionic2

I intend to disable the swipe gesture for the side menu in the log in page.
The only change I made is importing the MenuController and set swipeEnable to false in the constructor.

However, after running it, I keep getting a syntax error: Unexpected token (18:47) while parsing file.

```
import {App, Page, NavController, Nav,NavParams, IonicApp, Storage, LocalStorage, MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {httpService} from '../../services/httpService';
import {HelloIonicPage} from '../hello-ionic/hello-ionic';
import {GettingStartedPage} from '../getting-started/getting-started';
import {SettingsPage} from '../settings/settings';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/log-in/log-in.html',
  providers: [httpService]
})

export class LoginPage {

  static get parameters(){
     return [[NavController],[httpService],[MenuController]];
   }

   constructor(navController, httpService, menu: MenuController) {

     this.menu = menu;
     this.navController = navController;
     this.httpService = httpService;
     this.local = new Storage(LocalStorage);
     this.menu.swipeEnable(false);
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like `: MenuController` should be removed

Comment: I  have  a  similar  situation..any help would be thankful

Comment: This below solution for ionic 4. It's work for me. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610075/disable-menu-on-login-page-ionic-4#51637860)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Günter from the comments should be correct. Constructor should be:

```
constructor(navController, httpService, menu) {...}
```

When you use plain es6 javascript you have to declare your injectables in the *static get parameters()* function. Then in the constructor you declare the variable name that represents each injectable in the same order you declared the injectables in the returned array. The colon syntax is used when you use TypeScript and is later transpiled to the plain es6 javascript notation. In other words, the colon syntax is syntactical sugar that is only available if your app is configured to handle TypeScript.

Comment: Pat Murray Really helpfull ... Could you please explain a little bit of code so i can up vote ...

Answer (score 15):

The following worked for me on Ionic2 v.2.2.0

1. Open `src/app/app.html` and add an ID to your `<ion-menu>` element

So that this,

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
```

Becomes this.

```
<ion-menu id="myMenu" [content]="content">
```

2. Open `login.html` and remove the `<ion-navbar>` code from `<ion-header>` so that the menu will not display on the page.
3. Open `login.ts` and import the `MenuController` from `ionic/angular`.

In the constructor set `enable()` on `MenuCtrl` to `false` and add the menu ID as the second parameter. Even though the menu isn't showing, doing this will prevent the user from swiping to open the menu.

#### Example login.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public menuCtrl: MenuController
  ) {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(false, 'myMenu');
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution help to me

Answer (score 5):

```
import {  MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(....... ........ .......... .......,private menu : MenuController)


ionViewDidEnter() {
    // the root left menu should be disabled on this page
    this.menu.enable(false);
  }

  ionViewWillLeave() {
    // enable the root left menu when leaving this page
    this.menu.enable(true);
  }
```

this will hide the menu

Answer (score 0):

**With Ionic v3.5.3** 
1. Side menu: `src/app/app.html` 
     `<ion-menu [content]="content" id="menuId">`

2. In the `login.html`

 - import `MenuController`

 - in the contructor:

```
constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, public menuCtrl: MenuController) {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(false, 'menuId');
    // => menuId is the optional param
}
```

*[Read More](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/app/MenuController/#enable)*

Answer (score -1):

This below solution for ionic 4. It's work for me.

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.menuCtrl.enable(false);
}
```

[disable menu on login page ionic-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610075/disable-menu-on-login-page-ionic-4#51637860)