# disable menu on login page ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, angular6, ionic4

I use the beta of ionic 4 for the first time.
I try to disable the menu on a login page, but i have some trouble.

I've created the app with ionic-cli and the sidemenu template, then I generated a login page.

I removed the `<ion-split-pane>` from the app.component.html

I modified the app-routing.module.ts to redirect to my login screen.
In my login file, I tried to put an ngOnInit event to disable the menu on this specific page

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterContentInit, AfterViewInit,OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit, AfterContentInit, AfterViewInit,OnDestroy {
  constructor(public menuCtrl: MenuController) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(false);
    this.menuCtrl.swipeEnable(false);
  }
  ngAfterContentInit()  {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(false);
    this.menuCtrl.swipeEnable(false);
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(false);
    this.menuCtrl.swipeEnable(false);
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(true);
    this.menuCtrl.swipeEnable(true);
  }
}
```

I alto tried with an id set in ion-menu

```
<ion-menu swipeEnabled="true" #menu>
```

and change my code with

```
this.menuCtrl.enable(false, 'menu');
```

It's not working, can some one help me please.

Thank's

Comment: instead menu disable you can use *ngIf condition

Comment: Try this [How to disable side menu in ionic 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51802594/how-to-disable-side-menu-in-ionic-4/51802941#51802941)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Ionic 6** still supports `ionViewWillEnter`, use below code:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.menuCtrl.enable(false);
}
```

You can find full example [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/src/app/pages/tutorial/tutorial.ts#L47).

Comment: When I do this, I see the menu for a short time before it is gone. :(

Comment: I only copy/pasted this snippet... works like a charm!

Comment: This works fine for me on the first visit to the page but on the second navigation to the page the menu appears... help?
[EDIT] I found that i had `ionViewDidLeave(){this.menuCtrl.enable(true)}` on the page I was exiting that overpowered it

Comment: this doesn't work for me, I need to "setTimout" the action to work

Answer (score 10):

In my case in ionic 4 app, I did the following in welcome.page.ts file. welcome.page.ts is the page in which I want to hide split pane.

```
import {  MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';

constructor( public menuCtrl: MenuController){}

ionViewWillEnter() {
 this.menuCtrl.enable(false);
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer. One thing I want to clarify, where did you call the method ionViewWillEnter() ? 
I put the command in ngOnInit and it's working correctly but wanted to be clear about your method.

Answer (score 7):

Ionic 4 you would use the disabled property on ion-menu to hide on login.

```
<ion-menu [disabled]="!isLoggedIn"></ion-menu>
```

Comment: Ya. It work. Now I am able to switch between two menu in one app with this condition.

Comment: Where exactly would I store this `isLoggedIn` variable?

Comment: In the above example, "isLoggedIn" would be referenced from app.component.ts

Answer (score 5):

Solved my issue using

```
<ion-menu [swipeGesture]="false" ...>
```

Comment: The shortest solution to fix in ionic 4. Thanks.

Comment: Thank You so much, this was so useful after setting the '''menuController.enable(false)'''.

Answer (score 2):

The complete solution will be first ionViewWillEnter (meaning when it enters the login page you need to disable the side menu) using the code below

```
  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(false);
  }
```

then when you leave the side menu you need to re-enable it, else it will disable it through out the full application

Note: Do not forget to call the public menuCtrl: MenuController on your constructor

```
  ionViewDidLeave() {
    // enable the root left menu when leaving the tutorial page
    this.menuCtrl.enable(true);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually disabling it i think you should disable the swipe in ion-menu like this:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" [swipeEnabled]="false">
   Your code
</ion-menu>
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

and in the login page

```
<ion-header>

 <ion-navbar>
   <ion-title text-center>Login</ion-title>
 </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

This way menu will be disabled in the Login Page.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to do it

```
constructor(public menu: MenuController) {
    this.menu.swipeGesture(false)
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me, now, I am viewing the webpage version, not on mobile, but I want to hide on all. I incorporated this into my login-screen.ts and the menu is still visible.

Answer (score 0):

none of the above answers worked for me.

I did a test to check the order in which the methods were executed and this is what I got:

1.initializeApp

2.ngOnInit

2.1 platform ready

[image app.component.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOHY2.png)

example, console output, from **platfor ready** within **initializeApp** [image output initializeApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcvvL.png)

the console.log ('ionViewDidEnter') inside the ionViewDidEnter was never displayed by console

try the following scenario for yourself where the above described is evident

*sorry for my English*

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public selectedIndex = 0;
  public appPages = [
    {
      title: 'Inbox',
      url: '/folder/Inbox',
      icon: 'mail'
    },
    {
      title: 'Outbox',
      url: '/folder/Outbox',
      icon: 'paper-plane'
    },
    {
      title: 'Favorites',
      url: '/folder/Favorites',
      icon: 'heart'
    },
    {
      title: 'Archived',
      url: '/folder/Archived',
      icon: 'archive'
    },
    {
      title: 'Trash',
      url: '/folder/Trash',
      icon: 'trash'
    },
    {
      title: 'Spam',
      url: '/folder/Spam',
      icon: 'warning'
    }
  ];
  public labels = ['Family', 'Friends', 'Notes', 'Work', 'Travel', 'Reminders'];

  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private menu: MenuController
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    console.log('initializeApp');
    
    return this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      console.log('platform ready')
      this.statusBar.styleDefault()
      this.splashScreen.hide()
      // // -------------------------------------------------// 
      // this.menu.enable(false, "custom")                   //
      // this.menu.isEnabled('custom').then((enable)=>{      // => yes working
      //   console.log('enable from platform ready', enable);//
      // });                                                 //
      // //--------------------------------------------------//
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit');
    //  // ---------------------------------------------// 
    //  this.menu.enable(false, "custom")               //
    //  this.menu.isEnabled('custom').then((enable)=>{  // => yes working
    //    console.log('enable from ngOnInit', enable);  //
    //  });                                             //
    //  //----------------------------------------------//
    const path = window.location.pathname.split('folder/')[1];
    if (path !== undefined) {
      this.selectedIndex = this.appPages.findIndex(page => page.title.toLowerCase() === path.toLowerCase());
    }
  }
  ionViewDidEnter(){
    console.log('ionViewDidEnter')
    //  // ---------------------------------------------// 
    //  this.menu.enable(false, "custom")               //
    //  this.menu.isEnabled('custom').then((enable)=>{  // => not working
    //    console.log('enable ionViewDidEnter', enable);//
    //  });                                             //
    //  //----------------------------------------------//
  }

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane contentId="main-content">
    <ion-menu contentId="main-content" type="overlay" menuId="custom" id="custom">
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list id="inbox-list">
          <ion-list-header>Inbox</ion-list-header>
          <ion-note>hi@ionicframework.com</ion-note>

          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages; let i = index">
            <ion-item (click)="selectedIndex = i" routerDirection="root" [routerLink]="[p.url]" lines="none" detail="false" [class.selected]="selectedIndex == i">
              <ion-icon slot="start" [ios]="p.icon + '-outline'" [md]="p.icon + '-sharp'"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>{{ p.title }}</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-list>

        <ion-list id="labels-list">
          <ion-list-header>Labels</ion-list-header>

          <ion-item *ngFor="let label of labels" lines="none">
            <ion-icon slot="start" ios="bookmark-outline" md="bookmark-sharp"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>{{ label }}</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet id="main-content"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```

Comment: It would be great if you could explain your solution. It can help others looking for an answer for a similar problem. It can be hard for some people to spot the problem or in this case, your fix just by looking at the code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.